# How to get individual values from dropdown menus which have been added to a table of unknown size in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get individual values from dropdown menus. These values have been added to a table of unknown size in html. I would like to calculate the total price of these drinks. If I add a new drink to my data base, the code should be able to calculate the price of the new drink.

I want to reference each individual dropdown menus in order to calculate individual quantities, Is this possible in html?

If not, is there a way in java script to reference each one?

in python, I know you can add them all to an array, and work with each item in the array, but <I don't know how to do this in java script and html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Beverages</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
<div class="wa-top">
  
  <div class="wa-bar wa-blue wa-card wa-right-align wa-large"> 
      <a class="wa-bar-item wa-button wa-hide-medium wa-hide-large wa-right wa-padding-large wa-hover-white wa-large wa-blue" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a> 
      <a href="#" class="wa-bar-item wa-button wa-padding-large wa-white">Home</a> 
      <a href="#" class="wa-bar-item wa-button wa-hide-small wa-padding-large wa-hover-white">Beverages</a> 
      <a href="#" class="wa-bar-item wa-button wa-hide-small wa-padding-large wa-hover-white">Link 2</a> 
      <a href="#" class="wa-bar-item wa-button wa-hide-small wa-padding-large wa-hover-white">Link 3</a> 
      <a href="#" class="wa-bar-item wa-button wa-hide-small wa-padding-large wa-hover-white">Link 4</a>   
      <div class="logo"><a href="../home.html" class="wa-logo"><img src="images/17GLogo.png" alt="17g Webapp" /></a></div>
  <!-- Navbar on small screens -->
  <div id="navDemo" class="wa-bar-block wa-white wa-hide wa-hide-large wa-hide-medium wa-large"> 
      <a href="#" class="wa-bar-item wa-button wa-padding-large">Link 1</a> 
      <a href="#" class="wa-bar-item wa-button wa-padding-large">Link 2</a> 
      <a href="#" class="wa-bar-item wa-button wa-padding-large">Link 3</a> 
      <a href="#" class="wa-bar-item wa-button wa-padding-large">Link 4</a> 
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <% if (messages.success) { %>
      <p class="alert alert-success mt-4"><%- messages.success %></p>
      <% } %>
      <br />
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <% if(data.length){ for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {%>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><%= (i+1) %></th>
            <td><%= data[i].name%></td>
            <td>$ <%= data[i].price%></td>
            <td>
        <form action="insertlabel.php" id="privtelabel" method="POST">
            Product:
            <label for="beverages"></label>
            <select name="beverages" id="beverages">
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
      <br> Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity" id='quantity' required><br> Size:
     <select name='size' id='size'>
      <option value="Regular Milk">Regular Milk</option>
      <option value="Oat Milk">Oat Milk</option>
      <option value="Light Milk">Light Milk</option>

    </select>

    <p></p>


    Price: <span id="totalCost"></span>

  </form>
          </td>
          </tr>
          <% } }else{ %>
          <tr>
            <td>No record found</td>
          </tr>
          <% } %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your code which calculates the total? It sounds like you just need a loop

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to calculate(SUM) the value your select box(dropdown) you can do it like this. however, I didn't get your question properly.
*Make sure you've included jQuery.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   total_cost = 0;
     $('#beverages option').each(function(){
        total_cost = total_cost + parseInt($(this).val())
     })
    alert(total_cost)
 })
</script>
```